# Grails Plugin Creation: "No file extensions list found for path not being watched"

Tags: grails

I've created a Grails plugin using `grails create-plugin` with Grails v2.4.3.

I've added the Tomcat plugin to the `BuildConfig.groovy` with

```
build(":tomcat:7.0.55") {
    export = false
}
```

** Edit: I've placed this project [on GitHub](https://github.com/ecowden/please-reload-grails-plugin).*

I start the plugin with `grails run-app`. The plugin loads and I can see a dummy controller I created.

I'd like plugin development to work like regular ol' Grails development. If I run it and make a change, it would be nice to have the change hot-reloaded instead of having to restart it.

If I make any change, it does not update the running plugin. Instead, I receive the error,

** Edit: This error also happens in any project that uses the plugin, effectively breaking development mode.*

```
| Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No file extensions list found for path not being watched
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher.run(WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher.java:87)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:154)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectWatcher.run(GrailsProjectWatcher.java:161)
| Error     at java_lang_Runnable$run.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess.startProjectWatcher(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy:748)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess$_setupReloading_closure17.doCall(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy:737)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess$_setupReloading_closure17.doCall(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:504)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
WARNING: There was an error setting up reloading. Changes to classes will not be reflected: No file extensions list found for path not being watched
```

Anyone have any ideas? Any way to make this work?

Comment: I've shared the following project to demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/ecowden/please-reload-grails-plugin.

Comment: Also: I've found that this problem occurs not just when running the plugin, but when running any project that uses the plugin. This is a Big Deal for us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue, it looks like a bug. I have created a bug report: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11665.

It is not clear to me why it is also triggered by an installed plugin.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! For the installed plugin, I'm guessing the problem is because I used the `grails.plugin.location.'plugin-name' = '/plugin/path' method to install the plugin. That makes sense if it's from Grails scanning IDE folders as your bug report suggests.

Comment: .. it got fixed today and is scheduled for 2.4.4.